# pdfjs-dist package problem while build process

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js

I am having a problem with the pdfjs-dist package while building processing. It is showing an error in GitLab build image.

node version ---- v14.19.0

pdfjs-dist version-2.13.313

```
/app/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:2440
    return this._jsActionsPromise ||= this._transport.getPageJSActions(this._pageIndex);
                                  ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/cjs/core.min.js:1:94)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
```

Comment: node -v 14.19.0

Comment: try it : npm i pdfjs-dist --ignore-engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to node 16 resolved my problem, you might want to try that (if possible, of course) :)

Comment: Unfortunately at that time, I couldn't upgrade my node version because the whole big project was built on v14. But, instead of upgrading my node version I have downgraded my pdfjs-dist version to 2.9 and that has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading my package version to 2.9.359 has resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, with a locally installed Node v14.x too. I did something similar to [Elia. D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71307162/2653671), but since the binary file is self-contained with its own Node runtime, instead of upgrading my local Node version, I solved it by setting the target to use Node v16.